# Хранятся ли в DataTable исходные SQL типы?

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, ado.net

Я загружаю данные в DataTable из Access.

Когда я хочу получить тип колонки таким образом:

```
newDT.Columns[columnName].DataType.FullName
```

то получаю типы .Net.

Например вместо ShotText или LongText у меня отображается string.

Могу ли я как-нибудь достать SQL типы?

Comment: По идее, можно. Вот положительный ответ на ваш вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727771/276994 (но пусть кто-нибудь, знакомый с базами данных, подтвердит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить SQL-типы, когда данные *уже загружены* в `DataTable`, нельзя, но некоторую информацию можно извлечь *во время загрузки* данных.

Если для заполнения `DataTable` вы используете `OleDbDataAdapter`, то вместо этого нужно будет использовать `OleDbDataReader` и конкретно его метод `GetSchemaTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from TableName", connection);

using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable dtSchema = dr.GetSchemaTable();

    //берём из схемы интересующие нас мета-данные
    foreach (DataRow col in dtSchema.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}({2})",
            col["ColumnName"],
            (OleDbType)col["ProviderType"],
            col["ColumnSize"]);

    //загружаем данные
    dt.Load(dr);
}
```

Не знаю, насколько это может быть полезным, но у `OleDbDataReader` также есть метод `GetDataTypeName`:

```
using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable dtSchema = dr.GetSchemaTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(dr.GetDataTypeName(i));

    dt.Load(dr);
}
```